# Loop of regressions in R

Tags: r, regression

I have a regression problem that I implement in R using for loop. Basically, I have an equation (as a result of a long procedure) as a function of temperature, with five unknown parameters. I have 12 different temperatures that I can use to drive the equations, so for each combination of the five parameters, I can have 12 points.

The 12 points are actually derived from two line segments that cross at a certain point. Depending on the values of the five unknown parameters, the two segments can run anywhere. With the right parameters I hope that the two segments form a straight line.

For that purpose, I need to run a linear regression on these  points, and then over the whole combination of the five parameters, I need to find one set of parameters that results in the minimum residual sum of squares.

The problem is that it takes hours to solve the parameters with a fine resolution (by=0.05 instead of by=0.5 in the example below).

Is there a way to solve this problem faster? I think gradient descend can do this faster, but I do not know how to formulate it.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
A1 = 1.25
A2 = 0.01136
A3 = -0.0433

a = seq(0,1,by=0.5)
b = seq(0,1,by=0.5)
c = seq(-3,3,by=0.5)
d = seq(0,1,by=0.5)
e = seq(-3,3,by=0.5)

Temp_F = c(28.99, 36.87, 42.92, 52.84, 58.31, 67.60, 76.17, 70.20, 63.26, 53.05, 39.28, 35.35)

df <- expand.grid(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d, e=e)
nrow(df)

for (i in 1:nrow(df) ) {
    X.points = df$a[i]*A1 - (A2*df$b[i]*Temp_F) - df$c[i] + (A3*df$d[i]*Temp_F) + df$e[i]
     glm.X = glm(X.points ~ Temp_F)
     df$res[i]=sum(residuals(glm.X)^2)
}

write.csv(df, file="df.csv")
index=which(df$res == min(df$res[df$res > 0]))
    df$a[index]
df$b[index]
    df$c[index]
df$d[index]
    df$e[index]
```

Comment: It's still not entirely clear what you're doing. I start out feeling like I have understand the situation, but then as I pass from your third paragraph to your fourth, I find myself going "huh?". Repeated re-readings don't appear to reduce this remaining confusion. Can you clarify further, please?

Comment: The difficulty with this situation is that it presents us with an extremely inefficient solution to a problem that has not been adequately described. If you just want to speed it up, please post your question on SO. If you want a real *solution,* though, could you please elaborate on what is meant by "derived from two line segments that cross at a certain point" and "the two segments form a straight line"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite this as an optimisation problem. You have function with 5 parameters and you want to minimise it.

Define

```
 optf <- function(p) {
    a <- p[1]
    b <- p[2]
    c <- p[3]
    d <- p[4]
    e <- p[5]
    X.points = a*A1 - (A2*b*Temp_F) - c + (A3*d*Temp_F) + e
    sum(residuals(glm(X.points ~ Temp.F))^2)
 }
```

Now optimise:

```
 start <- c(0.5,0.5,0,0.5,0)
 optim(optf,start)
```

This should find the minimum of function `optf` **if it exists**. You can investigate different optimisation methods and try to play with starting values.

To speed things up use `lsfit` (`lsfit(Temp.F,X.points)` in your case) instead of `glm`, you have a linear problem and you do not need any extra calculations done by `glm`.

Comment: yes, this works. Thank you for making this problem clearer to me. The minimum does exists, but it seems there are zillions of local minimum. Each new starting points will result in a new minimum. Is there a way to have multiple function optimized simultaneously?

Comment: Try method="SA", theoretically it should find the global minimum. Also try plotting contour plots of your function to get an idea of how it behaves. Note also that if the optimisation algorithm has stopped this does not mean that minimum exists, check the gradient and the hessian.